# Trigger "Disparadores" Insert OR Update Mysql

Tags: mysql, trigger

Mi pregunta es respecto a la creación  de disparadores en `Mysql`

Actualmente cree el siguiente disparador:

```
CREATE TRIGGER movimientotEquipo AFTER INSERT ON movimiento
 FOR EACH ROW
 IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM equipo WHERE equipo.ide_af = NEW.af_ide) THEN

    UPDATE equipo  
     SET mov_ide = NEW.mov_ide, 
      est_equi = NEW.hard_estado
     WHERE equipo.ide_af = NEW.af_ide
ELSE 

INSERT INTO equipo (`ide_af`,`hard_ide`,`ide_ing`,`mov_ide`,`man_ide`,`est_equi`) 
VALUES (NEW.ide_af , NEW.hard_ide, '0' , NEW.mov_ide, '0', NEW.esta_ide );

END IF;
```

Pero me genera erro en  los `IF`

Si pruebo solamente la creación del `Insert` funciona...

Alguna sugerencia en `MYSQL`

## EDITADO

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El trigger lo creo por consola  y ahí esta todo el código que he intentado.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Coloca todo el código el TRIGGER; me parece esta incompleto además que no veo el BEGIN y el END. Y de ser posible el error especifico que te sale; no solo indicar donde se genera.

Comment: @RobertoLeónOramas  Edite la publicación,  pero  no tengo mas código para mostrar .. ese es todo lo que he intentado.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El problema es que en MySQL `EXISTS` es un operador que solo se puede utilizar en la cláusua `WHERE` de una consulta y no con la sentencia `IF`.

Intenta con el siguiente código:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER movimientotEquipo AFTER INSERT ON movimiento
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE vExists INT DEFAULT 0;
    SELECT
        1
    FROM
        DUAL
    WHERE
        EXISTS (SELECT * FROM equipo WHERE equipo.ide_af = NEW.af_ide)
    INTO
        vExists;

    IF vExists = 1 THEN
        UPDATE equipo SET
            mov_ide = NEW.mov_ide, 
            est_equi = NEW.hard_estado
        WHERE
            equipo.ide_af = NEW.af_ide;
    ELSE 
        INSERT INTO equipo (
            `ide_af`,
            `hard_ide`,
            `ide_ing`,
            `mov_ide`,
            `man_ide`,
            `est_equi`
        ) VALUES (
            NEW.ide_af,
            NEW.hard_ide,
            '0',
            NEW.mov_ide,
            '0',
            NEW.esta_ide
        );
    END IF;
END;$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Es Justo lo que necesitaba ..... Gracias!!!